# Android OverlayItem doesn't show a message

Tags: android, maps, overlay, android-mapview, overlayitem

thats my code:

```
OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "Test", "Hello");
itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
```

When i run this app i can see the map with my item on it, but when click on it nothing happens. I expected a kind of messagebox with "Test [...] Hello" in it. I guess i forgot something. Thank you for help.

Comment: Have you override the onTap(int index) method ?

Comment: in itemizedOverlay's class.........

Answer (score 1):

override the onTap(int index)  as below...........

```
   public class CustomItemizedOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {

   private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mapOverlays = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

   private Context context;

   public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker) {
        super(boundCenterBottom(defaultMarker));
   }

   public CustomItemizedOverlay(Drawable defaultMarker, Context context) {
        this(defaultMarker);
        this.context = context;
   }

   @Override
   protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
      return mapOverlays.get(i);
   }

   @Override
   public int size() {
      return mapOverlays.size();
   }

   @Override
   protected boolean onTap(int index) {
      OverlayItem item = mapOverlays.get(index);
      AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
      dialog.setTitle(item.getTitle());
      dialog.setMessage(item.getSnippet());
      dialog.show();
      return true;
   }

   public void addOverlay(OverlayItem overlay) {
      mapOverlays.add(overlay);
       this.populate();
   }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, but this effects a collapse in my application when I tab the item on the map. This is what logcat says, after tabbing the item: http://www1.xup.in/exec/ximg.php?fid=10663652

Comment: for testing set  if(null==item )Toast.makeText(context,"it is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(); dialog.setTitle("title");
      dialog.setMessage("Message");

Comment: Thank you Dheeresh Singh. Thats my onTap now: http://pastebin.com/sMDrY9f5     My app collapses anyway (and i dont get a message), when i tap on an item. I think this method is never called. Is that possible ?

Comment: Does somebady have an idea? =(